# How to strip trailing linebreaks from a string?

Tags: string, actionscript-3

I need to remove some redundant '\n's from the end of a csv I'm importing before it divides the lines up into an array (otherwise I get extra empty rows).

```
public function parseCSV(data:String):Array {

    //something to strip linebreaks, \n and \r from end of array

    var lines : Array = data.split ( /\R/ );
    var preamble : Array = lines.splice(0,trashLength);
    var keyArray : Array = lines.splice ( 0, 1 )[0].split ( "," );
    var assocArray : Array = [];
    for each (var line:String in lines)
    {
        var valArray : Array = line.split ( "," );
        var assoc : Object = {};
        for (var i : int = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++)
        {
            var key : String = keyArray[i];
            if (key != null && key != "") assoc[key] = valArray[i];
        }
        assocArray.push ( assoc );
    }

    return assocArray;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// normalize line endings to \n, because \r is not recognized as "end of line"
data = data.replace (/\s*\R/g, "\n");  
// remove leading and trailing whitespace
data = data.replace (/^\s*|[\t ]+$/gm, "");
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it actually is \n in this string (I didn't know what \R was before).  I tried your function and it removed one of the extraneous lines from the end, but there's still one left (there are 2 empty lines at the end of the CSV I'm importing)

Comment: It works for me - I had 4 empty lines in my test code.  Sure you're not counting the last newline added by trace?

Comment: It might be a single trailing newline character.  Add one more line: `data = data.replace (/\R$/, "");` This should fix it.

Comment: that did it awesome! would you be willing to explain the second two regex expressions briefly jus so I can appreciate what they are doing specifically?

Comment: @Damon: Sure. The second one matches all occurrences (/g) on each line (/m - if this is not set, ^ and $ will match the beginning and end of the string) of either any kind of whitespace (\s, this includes newline and linefeed) directly after the beginning of each line (^) or (|) occurrences of tab (\t) or space ( ) directly before the end of the line ($) and replaces them with an empty string.  The third one matches only one trailing newline just before the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was trying to remove stupid line endings from a file I was reading in line-by-line and I just used the first line of code you had here and replaced the "\n" with "". You're amazing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find replace only works on the first occurence of the target in the subject string. You can try array split / join instead.

```
public static function removeLineBreaks( s:String ) : String 
{ 
    return s.split("\r").join("\n");
}
```

or replace "\n" for "" if you want no delimiter.

Comment: Could you explain more how this works? I only want the linebreaks at the end of the string removed. wouldn't that just replace all the \r with \n? (in my string I have realized they are all \n actually, I'm trying right now to figure out what \R is...)

Comment: Huh? Spot Off! Replace works on all occurrences of the searched expression in the string, if you have the /g (global) option in the RegEx!